# Где можно найти документацию по VK Streaming API?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

С лета этого года ВКонтакте ужесточает лимиты на вызов методов newsfeed.search, wall.search и wall.get и предлагает использовать их новый Streaming API для интерактивного получения данных по этим методам, но нигде нет информации по использованию этого API. Кто знает где можно почитать документацию по Streaming API (в разделе для разработчиков у них пока ничего нет)?

Также интересуют данные по новым лимитам. Пока есть информация по количественному ограничению вызова метода newsfeed.search (до 100.000 запросов в сутки) с 07.06.2017. Кто-нибудь знает про другие ограничения?

Судя по новостям, разработчики VK планируют выпустить несколько версий Streaming API (основную и "расширенную"). Кто знает чем они будут отличаться (сейчас есть только информация, что "расширенная" версия будет выдавать "100% данных")?

Сама новость в Roadmap:
https://vk.com/dev/data_limits

Comment: Документации нигде нет. Тут только ждать официального релиза. Думаю не скоро будет, они до сих пор баги исправить не могут, которые год назад нашли.

Comment: А есть ли какая информация по частотные и количественные ограничения существующих методов newsfeed.search, wall.search и wall.get? Чтобы понимать  насколько сильно они урежут запросы к поиску. Что будет в итоге, 100.000 запросов в сутки или как у google к поиску - 100 бесплатных запросов, а остальное на коммерческих условиях?

Comment: @Александр Семикашев также там сказано о "расширенной" версии API, которая выдает "100% публичных данных". как понимаю, "нерасширенная" версия будет ограничена по времени (например, как у twitter - недельная давность)?

Comment: Да всё верно, я жду 7 июня, когда будет известно об ограничениях.

Comment: Я так думаю, что бесплатная версия будет реально урезанной. С нынешней политикой ВК хорошего ничего не будет.

Comment: @АлександрСемикашев по ограничениям с 7 июня - будет только резаться newsfeed.search до 100.000 запросов в сутки (что и понятно, на него приходилась основная нагрузка). вопрос в том, что останется в итоге. по поводу политики контакта придерживаюсь такого же мнения, что платформа идет в сторону facebook/instagram. в общем, все придет к vk private api)))

Comment: из личной переписки с разработчиками стало ясно, что в итоге сильно урежут суточное количество запросов.

Comment: Как и ожидалось, ничего хорошего

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Появилась документация по Streaming API:

```
https://vk.com/dev/streaming_api_docs
```

Но там реально жесть, в базовой версии максимальное количество запросов (правил), по которым поступают данные = 10 штук, в ответе выдается 1% от всей доступной информации (говоря русским языком не выдается практически ничего)).

Также сервер должен держать постоянное соединение через WebSockets, которое сервер может произвольно разорвать по прошествии определенного времени (в общем, это весьма неудобно).

Из текущего, с 21.06.2017 начинают действовать следующие ограничения по методам newsfeed.search, wall.search и wall.get:

- метод newsfeed.search можно вызывать не более 25000 раз в сутки;
- метод wall.search можно вызывать не более 2500 раз в сутки;
- метод wall.get можно вызывать не более 500000 раз в сутки.

Из личной переписки с разработчиками стало ясно, что в итоге сильно урежут суточное количество запросов, будет гораздо ниже вышеуказанных. Пока не ясно, будут ли вводить review (ручную модерацию) приложений по типу instagram, но в свете "борьбы со злоупотреблениями обхода ограничений" мне это видится единственным реальным шагом со стороны разработчиков VK, чтобы эти "злоупотребления" прекратить.